# Pandas: select row if value is included in a predefined list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to solve a issue WITHOUT a for-loop.
I have a a list `keys` which contains multiple strings. In the example 2 but inreality multiple hundreds. And I want to select all rows of `df` for which the value of `df["a]"` is included in `keys`.

```
keys = ["z","x"]
df =pd.DataFrame({"a": ["z", "y", "x"],
              "b": [15,85,23]})
```

I could write a for-loop which check for every row whether `df.a.iloc[i] in keys` but ther must be a way to directly index this.
So what I am looking for is something along the lines of

```
df[df.a in keys]
```

which does not work.

Comment: `df[df['a'].isin(keys)]`

Comment: ```isin``` instead of ```in```

Comment: Yeah thanks. I was so close yet sofar